# Django REST ModelSerializer --- General Question

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am working through a tutorial that includes the building of an articles app. I have an Article model that I am serializing and I am curious about why I need to explicitly set certain fields when using a ModelSerializer.

Here is my model:

```
from django.db import models

from core.models import TimestampedModel


class Article(TimestampedModel):
    slug            = models.SlugField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
    title           = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    description     = models.TextField()
    body            = models.TextField()
    author          = models.ForeignKey('profiles.Profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articles')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Pretty standard stuff. Next step is to serialize the model data in my serializers.py file:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = ProfileSerializer(read_only=True) # Three fields from the Profile app
    description = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    slug = serializers.SlugField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = (
        'author',
        'body',
        'createdAt',
        'description',
        'slug',
        'title',
        'updatedAt',
    )
```

Specifically, why do I need to explicitly state the `author`, `description`, and `slug` fields if I am using `serializers.ModelSerializer` and pulling those fields in from my model in my `class Meta:` below?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Django-Rest-Framework documentation, [drf-docs/model_serializer/specifying-which-fields-to-include](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include) it says:

> If you only want a subset of the default fields to be used in a model serializer, you can do so using fields or exclude options, just as you would with a ModelForm. It is strongly recommended that you explicitly set all fields that should be serialized using the fields attribute. This will make it less likely to result in unintentionally exposing data when your models change.

Therefore by using `fields =`  in the Serializer `META`, you can specify just the needed fields, and not returning vital fields like `id`, or exessive information like updated and created timestamps.

You can also instead of using `fields`, use `exclude`, which again takes in a tuple, but just excludes the fields you don't want.

These are especially useful when your database table contains a lot of information, returning all this information, especially if it is listed, can result in large return JSON's, where the frontend may only use a small percentage of the sent data.

DRF has designed their framework like this to specifically combat these problems.

Comment: Right, but in my case, above Meta, I am explicitly setting those three fields. Is it completely redundant for me to do so since I am just going to declare those same three fields again in my class Meta? Is it only necessary for me to explicitly define fields if I need to include other attributes, ex: 'required=False' in my description/slug field. I assume those fields would have been True had I not explicitly stated otherwise. @jupiar

Comment: I see what you mean. I would suspect why they don't automatically include what you specified in the fields is because of most of the time we build new serializers that inherit other serializers, but those inherited serializers might not want to return all the fields that the base serializer has specified. Therefore although might seem like doing double the work in writing out what fields you need twice, in large-scale applications that I encounter, with lots of serializer inherits, specifying exactly which fields are needed helps a lot. Hope that helps.

Comment: Much appreciated. I will double check these fields as I finish working through this tutorial. I'm about halfway through, and every instance involving the use of the inherited ModelSerializer indicates that we are changing the default serializer attribute for each field.https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/

Comment: If you are interested, a few days ago I posted a question about how to define fields on the fly without writing serializers in a file, where I overode the default ```__init__()``` to allow fields to be passed at runtime, the code in that post may help you to see why passing specific fields in has advantages. It's still unanswered and I still havn't figured out a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568714/how-to-return-data-from-nested-serializers-inside-serializers-built-on-the-fly

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we should define field in serializer for:

- Your api use serializer don't need all data of your models. Then you can limit field can get by serializer. It faster if you have so much data.
- You dont want public all field of your model. Example like `id`
- Custom field in serializer like `serializers.SerializerMethodField()` must define in `fields` for work

Finally, iF you dont want, you can define serializer without define `fields`. Its will work normally